# How to get currently logged-in user in signals.py file?

Tags: python, django, django-signals, django-email, django-messages

I'm making a **todo app** and one of it's functionalities is **to send an email** to the user that **his task was overdue**.

Part of the **views.py** file:

```
from .models import Todo
from django.utils import timezone
from .signals import overdue

def index(request):
    ...
    overdue_tasks = Todo.objects.filter(time__lte=timezone.now())
    if overdue_tasks:
        overdue.send_robust(sender=Todo)
    ...
    return render(request, 'todo/index.html', {'overdue_tasks' : overdue_tasks })
```

Part of the **signals.py** file:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver, Signal
from .models import Todo
from django.core.mail import send_mail

overdue = Signal()
user_email = request.user.email

@receiver(overdue)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    send_mail('Subject', 'Your task was Overdue !', 'myemail@gmail.com', 'user_email', fail_silently=False)'
```

It's raising exception:

> "NameError: name 'request isn't defined."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are tryng to acess te request trough `request.user.email` without a request to acess, you can acess the user email on `index` view, pass the email as a **kwarg and acess on `my_handler`

```
def index(request):
    ...
    overdue_tasks = Todo.objects.filter(time__lte=timezone.now())
    if overdue_tasks:
        overdue.send_robust(sender=Todo, email=request.user.email)
    ...
    return render(request, 'todo/index.html', {'overdue_tasks' : overdue_tasks })

@receiver(overdue)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    email = kwargs.get('email')
    send_mail(foo)
```